# RAND() cause miscalculation in "Link to Sheets"

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

`=IF($AI$2<>"",AH34,$AJ$2+($AK$2-$AJ$2)*rand())`

That formula is used to freeze rand() value.

I am able to "Link to spreadsheets" on Google Docs / Google Slides, but right after the copy, it asked to "Update". I clicked the "Update" and it show a different value.

Answer (score 1):

RAND() can't be frozen by using a formula as it's recalculated every time that a spreadsheet is opened and following the rules of File > Spreadsheet settings... > Calculation.

Instead of RAND() you could try to use a script.

Related

- [Google Spreadsheet generate random numbers with Math.random()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70488/88163)